# Microsoft teams - Get list of all the members in that team using bot (node js)

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am developing a bot in microsoft teams using node js sdk 4. I have installed the app in a team and i want to know the list of members in that team using my bot. I have tried this code (below) but only getting data of only one member(myself) .

```js
async getAllMembers(context) {
        var continuationToken;
        var members = [];
        do {

            var pagedMembers = await TeamsInfo.getPagedMembers(context,10, continuationToken);   //return my data only
            continuationToken = pagedMembers.continuationToken;
            members.push(...pagedMembers.members);
        } while (continuationToken !== undefined);
        for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
            console.log(members[i]);
        }
        return members;
    };
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try getting roster for the Team. Here is the code [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=typescript#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q-2_typescript):

> ```js
> export class MyBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
>     constructor() {
>         super();
>
>         // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
>         this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => {
>             const teamDetails = await TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails(turnContext);
>             if (teamDetails) {
>                 await turnContext.sendActivity(`The group ID is: ${teamDetails.aadGroupId}`);
>             } else {
>                 await turnContext.sendActivity('This message did not come from a channel in a team.');
>             }
>
>             // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
>             await next();
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The same was happening to me. The reason was that I was sending a direct message to the bot.
The code is supposed to be used inside a Teams channel context. That way, the bot has access to all the team members that belong to that channel.

```
    private async Task MessageAllMembersAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var teamsChannelId = turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetChannelId();
        var serviceUrl = turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl;
        var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(_appId, _appPassword);
        ConversationReference conversationReference = null;

        var members = await GetPagedMembers(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        ...
```